# sveltekit: await on data from +server.ts load function

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am building a simple sveltekit web app, where I first fetch some data from my database and then want to display it.

For that I created a simple route with a +page.svelte and +page.server.ts file.

+page.svelte:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import type {PageData} from './$types';
    export let data: PageData
</script>

<div class="container">
    <article class="prose p-5">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <h4>Some text</h4>
    </article>
    <DataComponent data={data.items}/>
</div>
```

+page.server.ts:

```
import type {PageServerLoad, RouteParams} from "./$types";

export const load = (async ({params}: { params: RouteParams }) => {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        redirect: 'follow'
    };
    let data = await fetch("databaseURL", requestOptions)
    return {
        "items": await data.json()
    }
}) satisfies PageServerLoad;
```

The problem that I am having is, that I can't find a way to "await" for the data.

It takes quite a while for the data to load, so I want to use an `{#await}` block, to show a loading animation in the meantime, but I can't get it to work.

The whole page is waiting for the data to fetch, before it renders. Do I have to create a seperate async API function which I then import an then can await on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the data from the top level of the data to a sub-level, see documentation on [streaming with Promises](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#streaming-with-promises):

> Promises at the top level of the returned object will be awaited, making it easy to return multiple promises without creating a waterfall. When using a server load, nested promises will be streamed to the browser as they resolve. This is useful if you have slow, non-essential data, since you can start rendering the page before all the data is available

```js
return {
  streamed: {
    items: fetch("databaseURL", requestOptions).then(d => d.json()),
  },
}
```

Note that this will not work on all platforms.

Alternatively you can create a custom [API endpoint](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server) and `fetch` from the client.

Answer (score 3):

you can stream with a Promise in +page.server.ts:

```
export const load = ( () => {
  const apidata = fetch(databaseURL, requestOptions)
    .then(response => {
       return response.json()
    })
    .catch(() => {
       console.log(error)
       return error
    })
    
  return {
    streamed: {
      items: new Promise((resolve) => {  
         apidata
          .then(data => {
             return resolve(data)
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
          })
      })
    }
  }
}) satisfies PageServerLoad;
```

And then display a loading component while awaits for the data and then the data-component like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import type {PageServerLoad, RouteParams} from "./$types"

  //this export gets the data from the +server page
  export let data: PageServerLoad
</script>
{#await data.streamed.items}
  <LoadingComponent />
{:then items}
  <DataComponent data={items}/> 
{/await}
```

You can additionally (and recommended!) add a {:catch} block after the  to display anything you want to handle the error.

```
{:then items}
  <DataComponent data={items}/> 
{:catch error}
  <p class="error">Something went wrong</p>
{/await}
```